# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter. Как задать pattern для записи даты Apache access log-a?

Tags: java, apache

Пытаюсь создать паттерн чтобы разобрать дату/время Apache Access Log-a. Пример

```
'30/Nov/2016:04:13:36 +0200'
```

Задаю паттерн

```
private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z");
```

В результате получаю exception при использовании метода parse:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '30/Nov/2016:04:13:36 +0200' could not be parsed at index 3
```

Как правильно задать паттерн для DateTimeFormatter-a? Вроде бы делаю все по документации, и все равно что-то не то.

Edit:
    Для шаблона

```
formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss Z");
String datetime = "30/Nov/2016:04:13:36 +0200";
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime, formatter);
```

Выдает точно такой же exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '30/Nov/2016:04:13:36 +0200' could not be parsed at index 3
```

Comment: попробуйте при создании форматтера локаль (английскую или ROOT) указать

Comment: Да, сработало. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main{

    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String datetime = "30/Nov/2016:04:13:36 +0200";
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime, formatter);

        System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toString());
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/ojxwIQ

Как ни странно оригинальный шаблон компилируется и выполняется без ошибок на https://www.compilejava.net/.

Как оказалось причина проста - нужно указывать locale, иначе по неведомым мне причинам оно отказывается парсить в Idea.

```
 private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z").withLocale(Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через точку после форматера, например дата сегодня:

```
ZonedDateTime.now().format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME );
```

или

```
System.out.println("RFC_1123_DATE_TIME =" + ZonedDateTime.now().format( DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME ));
```

выдаст:  Thu, 28 Oct 2021 12:33:27 +0300

#### не забываем библиотеку:

- import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
- import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

пример форматов:

- ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME  = 2021-10-28T12:33:27.627
- ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME = 2021-10-28T12:33:27.66+03:00
- ISO_DATE_TIME =        2021-10-28T12:33:27.66+03:00[Europe/Kiev]
- BASIC_ISO_DATE =       20211028+0300
- ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME =  2021-10-28T12:33:27.661+03:00[Europe/Kiev]
- RFC_1123_DATE_TIME =   Thu, 28 Oct 2021 12:33:27 +0300

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss Z")
```

где:

- **dd** день в двузначном формате
- **MMM** сокращенное название месяца
- **yyyy** год
- **hh** часы
- **mm** минуты
- **ss** секунды
- **Z** часовой пояс

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Для вашего случая `ZonedDateTime` получается так:

```
String datetime = "30/Nov/2016:04:13:36 +0200";
TemporalAccessor time = DateTimeFormatter
                           .ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z")
                           .parse(datetime);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(
            time.get(YEAR),
            time.get(MONTH_OF_YEAR),
            time.get(DAY_OF_MONTH),
            time.get(HOUR_OF_DAY),
            time.get(MINUTE_OF_HOUR),
            time.get(SECOND_OF_MINUTE));

ZoneId zone = ZoneOffset.from(time);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, zone);
```

Comment: Тот же exception:
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '30/Nov/2016:04:13:36 +0200' could not be parsed at index 3

Comment: У меня все работает, проверяйте лучше.

Comment: Уже нашел причину, спасибо за старания:)